# Order of bytes after BitArray to byte[] conversion

Tags: c#, arrays, byte, bit, bitarray

I'm, trying to figure out bytes order after conversion from BitArray to byte[].

Firstly, here is the BitArray content:

```
BitArray encoded = huffmanTree.Encode(input);

foreach (bool bit in encoded)
{
    Console.Write((bit ? 1 : 0));
}

Console.WriteLine();
```

Output:

```
Encoded: 000001010110101011111111
```

Okay, so if we convert these binary to Hex manually we will get: `05 6A FF`

However, when I am using conversion in C#, here is what I get:

```
BitArray encoded = huffmanTree.Encode(input);

byte[] bytes = new byte[encoded.Length / 8 + (encoded.Length % 8 == 0 ? 0 : 1)];
encoded.CopyTo(bytes, 0);
string StringByte = BitConverter.ToString(bytes);
Console.WriteLine(StringByte); // just to check the Hex
```

Output:

```
A0-56-FF
```

Nevertheless, as I have mentioned, it should be 05 6A FF. Please help me to understand why is that so.

Comment: bits are probably returned in LSB to MSB fashion when you foreach them. Looking at A0 you get `1010 0000` with the MSB on the left. But if you reverse it you get `0000 0101` or 05. Hex 6 and F stay the same when inverted (but switch places in the double hex).

Comment: I see. Is there any way to make the order correct?

Comment: Which of the two orders is "correct"? If you want to print out the 1's and 0's with the least-significant bit on the right, then iterate over the BitArray backwards (i.e. starting with the highest-index, most-significant bit, rather than the lowest-index bit)

Comment: Thank you guys, it is clear now! May I ask you to help me with the implementation? Once it is converted to bytes, I want to see it as 05 6A FF.

Sorry if I have confused you, thanks again.

Comment: Are you sure? I think it's more likely that your "Encoded" output should be reversed?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. Let me explain this to you. I am implementing Huffman coding, so it is the code that I have. I am writing it to a byte file, just to save it, and the bytes order is not "correct". This is work for my uni, and my teacher wants to see the hex in the mentioned order (05 6A FF). I have no idea why it is necessary, however, that is his requirement.

Comment: One straightforward way is `var reversed = new BitArray(encoded.Cast<bool>().Reverse().ToArray());`, which creates a new BitArray with the bits reversed. Then turn that into a string